# laravel validation with delete_at

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have one problem using **LARAVEL VALIDATION**.

**I Expect `deleted_at` is null but I am getting `deleted_at` = null**

```
'level_name' => 'unique:company_levels,level_name,' . $id . ',id,company_id,' . $company_id.',deleted_at,null',
```

It generates a Query like below

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `company_level` where `level_name` = 'Chennai' and `id` <> 1 and `company_id` = 3 and `deleted_at` = null
```

which is not matching my need.

I need to generate the query like below

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `company_level` where `level_name` = 'Chennai' and `id` <> 1 and `company_id` = 3 and `deleted_at` is null
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by replacing null to NULL.

use **capital NULL replace of null**

Exiting query

```
',deleted_at,null',
```

I replaced it by

```
',deleted_at,NULL',
```